# htaccess to redirect IE users visiting homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect all IE users visiting homepage(but not when they visit other pages on website) to certain page. I was trying to use code below but it is not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} *MSIE* [NC,AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$  
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ie.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from `*MSIE*`.
Should be `.*MSIE.*` or like that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /ie.html [R=301,L]
```